# vRealize automation 400 BAD_REQUEST "920002

Tags: automation, 400-bad-request

```
400 BAD_REQUEST "920002: Invoked action completed with error. Error : Action 'getEPGfromTag' in module 'com.vmware.library.tasks' failed : com.vmware.vapi.std.errors.unable_to_allocate_resource => {data=<unset>, error_type=UNABLE_TO_ALLOCATE_RESOURCE, messages=[com.vmware.vapi.std.localizable_message => {args=[], default_message=Too many networks. Add more filter criteria to reduce the number., localized=<unset>, id=com.vmware.api.vcenter.network.too_many_matches, params=<unset>}]}
```

I am getting the above error, checking my Actions in dev everything seems to be fine but in prod I cannot find any networks. The code hasn't changed in over a year so I am not sure why all of a sudden it would stop working. I found this article:

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/92932

and followed that and it doesn't seem to have fixed my issue at all. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone else going through this issue, I guess the API has a limit of 1000 networks and we have more than that so we had to rewrite some of our JS. The crazy thing is I am sure that the majority of those networks aren't being used at all.